# .NET core 3.0 RC vs Preview 9

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I just recently installed preview 9.  Looks like a Release Candidate will be available soon. This stuff is changing fast.
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md 
Just going off memory, will one need to uninstall Preview 9 before installing the RC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installers should automatically uninstall previous versions of the same release band, so the preview 9 installer (windows, judging from the `visual-studio` tag), should have uninstalled the preview 8 if present. A possible RC (if one is released before the final 3.0 version end of september) should also uninstall the preview.

But it is not necessary to uninstall it if you want to use the previews / RCs side-by-side. The side-by-side mechanism is the same as for different version of .NET Core and the .NET Core SDK. Not all projects need to use the same tooling / runtime (e.g. when you are migrating projects from preview8 to preview9 consecutively and thus want to work with both versions side-by-side).